# configuring the image file reducer Google Firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

The following google cloud function properly uploads an image, but I would also like to compress the image as to avoid unnecessary charges due to large files being uploaded.  I am using the image reducer extension from Firebase and it works but the issue is that the image file no longer shows up on my user table.  is there something i need to configure in the extension so that the image url in the user table is overwritten by the reduced image??

```
exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
  const BusBoy = require("busboy")
  const path = require("path")
  const os = require("os")
  const fs = require("fs")


  const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers })

  let imageToBeUploaded = {}
  let imageFileName

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    if (mimetype !== `image/jpeg` && mimetype !== `image/png`) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: `Not an acceptable file type` })
    }

    // my.image.png => ['my', 'image', 'png']
    const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[filename.split(".").length - 1]
    // 32756238461724837.png
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(
      Math.random() * 1000000000000
    ).toString()}.${imageExtension}`
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName)
    imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype }
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath))
  })

  busboy.on("finish", () => {
    admin
      .storage()
      .bucket(config.storageBucket)
      .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
          }
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`
        return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.uid}`).update({ imageUrl })
      })
      .then(() => {
        return res.json({ message: "image uploaded successfully" })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" })
      })
  })
  busboy.end(req.rawBody)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Resize Images extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images) only handles the resizing of the image in Cloud Storage. It does not update data in any other location, including Cloud Firestore. If you need such functionality, you'll need to create it yourself.

Also see:

- this discussion on the extensions open-source repo about [allowing to specify a callback that gets invoked after resizing](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/111).